# Error 3001 Excel VBA MySQL Select

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I'm trying to select rows in a MySQL database using Excel Macros. The connection appears to be working OK but I get a VBA 3001 error

> (Microsoft visual basic 3001 arguments are of the wrong type, or are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another)

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=localhost;" & _
    "DATABASE=talar;" & _
    "USER=root;" & _
    "PASSWORD=root;" & _
    "Option=3"         
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ots where Estado in (2,3)"   
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
Dim myArray()
myArray = rs.GetRows()
oConn.Close
```

MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver is installed, MySQL service is running fine, I am using Excel 2010, windows 7. anyone have any idea? thanks!

Comment: The SQL is set to a variable at "strSQL", it looks like the rs.Open is using variable "SQLStr"

Comment: i technique i use in for VBA is always make your variable Upper case/ Zebra Case, and always type in lower case ... if you don't see VBA auto correct it you know you typed it wrong.

Comment: Also - use `Option Explicit` - this is exactly what that's for...

Comment: I am doing this on the Excel ide, is no so user friendly! thanks Tim.

Comment: People take VBA Editor's *flexible-ness* for granted...at least 7 out of 10 noob coders miss Option Explicit and run into the unnecessary havoc! It is quite advisable to drop the *Hungarian notation* (data type prefix) which was used for weakly typed C language in the past. Follow option explicit and be consistent on your variable declaration and keep their purpose in mind when creating them. Why would you want to have *large* variants when an integer or a byte could do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've actually got two problems both of which would be easier to spot of you were using `Option Explicit`.

Both are in this line:

```
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

Your SQL string variable is `strSQL` and your connection object is `oConn`. So change the line of code to:

```
rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```